# Manually set textbox width, but let anchoring manage height in WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, anchor

I have a .NET 4 WinForms application with two multi-line textboxes side-by-side. I'd like each textbox to take half the available horizontal space, so I override OnLayout to manually calculate and set the width. However, I also want them to be resized vertically as the parent control is resized. I set anchoring for each to Top and Bottom, which is normally enough, but I find that if I set the Width property it messes up the height - they're a bit higher than they should be. As soon as I comment out the line that sets the Width the vertical resizing works fine again.

I worked around this by manually setting the height as well, but ideally I'd like to let WinForms anchoring to take care of this. Any way to do this? I've tried this in both OnResize and OnLayout events, both before and after calling the base method and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `SplitContainer` and and set `Panel1MinSize` and `Panel2MinSize` to half value of `SplitContainer` `Width`.

Also, you must `Dock` `Fill` both `TextBox` es so that each consume half of the available space.

[image]

Comment: That's a possibility, but I was hoping to avoid the extra complexity. I don't really need the user to be able to resize them. I just want them automatically resized, like anchoring normally does.